# How can write this regexp

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to identify a Bitcoin balance. (minimum +0.00000001 and maximum +10)

```
    0.00000001 -> true
    1 -> true
    1.00000 -> true
    1.0111 -> true
    0.5gg -> false
    0.01.2 ->false
    -0.123 -> false
    -1 -> false
```

Comment: You don't need a regex for that. Just use comparison operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your criteria, you could easily just use this:

```
^([0-9]|10)(\.\d+)?$
```

Here's a regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oJ7qP8/2

While this technically solves your problem using regular expressions, you shouldn't be parsing numbers with regex; use a combination of `is_number` and `floatval` and compare the numbers appropriately to a specific criteria.

Comment: Thank for replay but I changed it a little ^([0-9]|10)(\.\d{1,8}+)?$

Comment: Yup, that works too.